# How to find active app name?

Tags: java, android, clipboard, android-package-managers

I have this code that when I copy some text in clipboard this program paste text and application name automatically in the text box.I want paste app's name that running/on top

```
        myClipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged()
        {
            PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo ai;
            try {
                ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                ai = null;
            }
            final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
            ClipData cp = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
            ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0);
            String text1 = item.getText().toString();
            pastetext.setText(text1+"---"+applicationName);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of activities/applications installed on Android :

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

To check all running applications

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

If you want to fetch the package name of your app or currently opened app in android, than refer this http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-get-package-name-in-android.html

Hope this helps...